# Json data showing SyntaxError: Bad string on line 1

Tags: json

This is my sample data which i am using  can you help me how to solve this error

```
 {    
        "type": "institution",
            "title": "Sue Ryder1",
            "field_institution_setup_date": {        
            "und": [            {                
                "value": "2014-11-01",
                "value2": "2018-11-01"            
            }        ]    
        },
            "field_institution_user_limit": 100,
            "field_institution_product_access": {        
            "und": [            {                
                "code": "pfs"            
            },              {                
                "code": "lrn"            
            }        ]    
        },
            "field_logo": "533766"  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly valid JSON. Heres the formatted version for you to use.

```
{
    "type": "institution",
    "title": "Sue Ryder1",
    "field_institution_setup_date": {
        "und": [{
            "value": "2014-11-01",
            "value2": "2018-11-01"
        }]
    },
    "field_institution_user_limit": 100,
    "field_institution_product_access": {
        "und": [{
            "code": "pfs"
        }, {
            "code": "lrn"
        }]
    },
    "field_logo": "533766"
}
```